# Order filter layered navigation magento

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, layered-navigation, filter, navigation

I have some attributes (size, color, type ect).

I want to order them in layered navigation in category page.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. Go to **Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes**
2. Go to respective attribute code and click on it
3. Go to Position Field and change the value there
4. If you want size as first then followed by color and type. your Position value for the Size will be 1, it will be 2 for the Color etc.) Save it
5. Clear cache and check the page

Answer (score 3):

If attributes are already shown but not in your required order. You should edit each attribute and look for option "**Position**" probably is set as "**0**" just change it with the order number.

Answer (score 1):

Magento has configuration to position your attributes accordingly in layered navigation by default.

Just go to `Admin >> Catalog >> Attributes >> Manage Attributes >> Manufacturer`

Set **Position** (*Frontend Properties*) according to your need.

Comment: How to set Shop By SHOPPING OPTIONS by position like price 1, author 2, language 3, pages4, etc thanks