# Change order of configuration options in customer product view

Tags: magento2, attributes, configurable-product, product-attribute

I have configurable products with many attributes like size and color in **v2.2.7**.
They are listed in the **admin area** and in **Stores > Attributes > Attribute Set > Default**.
The order currently is **"Size"**, then **"Color"**.

But on the customers view for the product, attributes are listed as **"Color"** and then **"Size"**.

[image]

[This post](https://community.magento.com/t5/Just-Ask-Alan/Product-Configurations-Attribute-sort-order/m-p/27676/highlight/true#M216) in the magento forums outlines how to do it while creating a configurable product. However, if products are already created and you go to configuration options, there is not a way to edit attributes order without also recreating all configured products.

Making the change suggested in **"Stores > Attributes > Product > Storefront Properties"** from [this post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/55163/75936), changes the order of how things show up in layered navigation. But it doesn't change the order of configuration options the customer sees.

I'm trying to make **"Size"** appear above **"Color"** when customer is looking at product page. How do I change the order of configuration options for products already created?

**UPDATE**

- The order attributes show up in customer view / layered navigation is changed from **Stores > Attributes > Product > [attribute] > Storefront Properties > [Position]**.
- The order configuration options show up in customer view / product
  details page are controlled by `position` column in the
  `catalog_product_super_attribute` table (see accepted answer).
- The order attributes show up in admin section when adding new
  products is based on the order in **Stores > Attributes > Attribute
  Set > [set] > [Groups]**. Note that custom attributes added to the "Product Details" group don't always follow the order in v2.2.7. So it's best to click "**Add New**" under **Groups** and add the custom attributes you need to show up in a set order during product on-boarding to the group you created.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The position of the attributes of Configurable Product are stored at **catalog_product_super_attribute**

Use SQL to update position in PDP

```
192 = Id attribute Size
193 = Id Attribute Color
update catalog_product_super_attribute set position = 1 where attribute_id = 192 AND product_super_attribute_id <> 0;
update catalog_product_super_attribute set position = 2 where attribute_id = 193 AND product_super_attribute_id <> 0;
```

#### update:

Where you can find attribute id => You can look up in the table named `eav_attribute`

```
select attribute_id from eav_attribute where attribute_code = '[attribute code]';
```

Comment: Thank you! Please include update style that will work with mysql workbench safe mode, example: `UPDATE catalog_product_super_attribute set position = 1 WHERE attribute_id = 193 AND product_super_attribute_id <> 0;` and that to find the `attribute_id` needed, look in `eav_attribute` table for the attribute_id corresponding to the names (attribute_code's) to that should be updated.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Hi @HoangHieu, Your solution is working fine. But once you edit the product from admin, it lost its position again. Can you provide a permanent solution for it?
Thank you

Comment: Hi @SanchitGupta, I thought these attributes you are selected didn't order. Think you're selected Color -> Size (then the order is Color -> Size), you need to select Size first if you want to Color is next to Size.

Comment: Hi@HoangHieu! you are correct. Upvoted :) Happy coding

Answer (score 3):

- Go to **Product page** (Admin)
- **Configurations** then **Edit Configurations**
- Click **Next** to set **attribute value**
- Drag **Color** after **Size**
  [image]
- Hit **Next** until **Generate products**
- **Save** your product and **Reindex cache**
- Check on frontend

For future products attributes sorting

- Goto **Store -> Attributes -> Products**
- Open your desired **Attribute**
- Open tab *Storefront Properties*
- Set **Position** value here
- Example: 10 for size, 20 for color

Comment: what am I missing about your post? It looks like you read my post and re-posted how to perform steps I already outlined and linked to. You didn't address the problem of how to "change the order of configuration options for products already created". Your steps only affect layered navigation...which I already pointed out in my original post and the page to set position clearly states "Position of attribute in layered navigation block." is what it's for.

Comment: The steps that I have shared can apply on current products too. It's ok, @HoangHieu resolve your issue this is important :)